Recent browser update breaking loopback access - custom protocol (Windows)
Pardon if this is a board question, there won't be a lot of code supplied given the nature of the issue.
First, this is a legacy app, not my decision - I don't want to spend effort defending the implementation :-). My goal is to understand what broke, with intentions of replacing it with a better, more standardized implementation. But, I need to be able to pinpoint the root cause so that I can enumerate why it needs to change and what to change it to.
Background
A recent update in Chrome broke a browser loopback call to a custom protocol that displayed a Windows form for the user. This is similar to when a browser displays a dialog asking permission to open a local app, eg "The site is trying to open...".
window.checkProtocol("mycustomprotocol://params", () => {});
I could not find any Chrome release notes that would indicate there were any local resource hardening/or custom protocol changes implemented. Oddly enough, it works with FF v132.0.1.
I was able to get the functionality to work in Edge by adding an exemption with the following CheckNetIsolation LoopbackExempt -a -n="Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe".
Error Symptoms
During the action button click event, the dialog asking permission to open the local app is not displayed. Also, in the dev console, a 503 error was logged.
I figured it would be an easy case of the local service was not running but I was able to verify the service was running and listing on the expected port via netstat -a. As another configuration check, I used netsh http show sslcert to verify it was setup correctly and it checked out as well.
Next Steps

Find Chrome documentation to explain "breaking" change.

I'm open to any other debugging tips or pointers to unearth the change in browser functionality.

You've provided an architectural description, but probably you need to provide the data, and isolate the code before anyone can suggest what to do.
